# Full width table in a scrollingcontainer

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm about to create a table which is going to look like this one right here:

[image]

Now it's getting  tricky since the website is going to be responsive. That's why I thought it would be nice to wrap the table in a div `.cross-tab` which has `overflow: scroll`.

```
<div class="bs-example">
  <div class="cross-tab">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <? for ($i=0; $i < 19; $i++) { ?>

            <th>
              <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40" class="team-icon">
            </th>

          <? } ?>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

The div should have a certain width the `overflow: scroll`. So the table would be full-sized on any device but get cropped off on small screens with a scrollbar to scroll arround:

[image]

Is there a way to accomplish this with pure CSS or do I have to calculate the full table with with js and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix your problem with media query.

For example :

HTML

```
<body>

<div>
  <table  border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0"> 
    <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> 
    <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> 
    <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> 
    <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> 
    <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> 
  </table>
</div>

</body>
```

CSS

```
div 
{
  background : red;
  width:100%;
  overflow:auto;  
}

table 
{
  width :100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) 
{
  table 
  {
    width : 800px;    
  }
  div 
  {
    height:200px;
  }
}
```

codepen : http://codepen.io/ColoO/pen/xuACl